# How to monkey patch the node object?

Tags: chef-infra

I've got code in a chef_gem that does something like this:

```
 class Chef
   class Node
     def cool_thing
       # ... stuff ...
     end
   end
 end
```

And, the ruby gem definitely gets installed on the target host.   But, the `kitchen converge` test on my Chef recipe fails saying "Node does not have a `cool_thing` method".

I've been told by others that I have to do something like `::Chef::Node.send( ... magic ... )`, but I'm not sure what I need to do to make the magic.

Any thoughts, ideas, rants?

Answer (score -1):

You would have to require the gem to cause that code to be actually loaded. But really really don't do this. Find some other option, any option.